# Hide content if under transparent header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a transparent header which can't be a image or a color, it needs to be transparent. Whenever some divs slides under my header I want to hide only the part which is below it.

[Problem](https://codepen.io/eric_cartman/pen/wvvdyqB)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  height: 5rem;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.content {
  margin-top: 25rem;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 30rem;
  height: 5rem;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 }
```

```html
<div class="header"> Header</div>

<div class="content">  DONT SHOW THIS DIV UNDER HEADER</div>

<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

Comment: what is the real background of body ? an image ? a pattern gradient ? there can be a trick here, but if body background is not a plain color, it won't work

Comment: reminded me of an old question https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/gHDud (2013) , but could not find the question. You can remove the js if the bg do not need to scroll (pseudo element should be useless, it was for an old IE )

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can achieve this without javascript at all. You can put element "under" the `.header` with body's `background`, and set the proper `z-index` in order to keep it under.

Something like that:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  height: 5rem;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
z-index: 3;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 25rem;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
z-index: 1;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 30rem;
  height: 5rem;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 }
/* this will act as a mask to hide the content when it get "under" the header: */
#contentMask {background: inherit; z-index: 2; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; height: 5em; width: 100%;}
```

```html
<div class="header"> Header</div>
<div class="content">  DONT SHOW THIS DIV UNDER HEADER</div>
<div id="contentMask"></div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

Edit (as for comment):

You can play with z-index property in order to achieve it. This is a general example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100vh;
}
.header {
  height: 5rem;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 4;
}
#contentMask {
  background: inherit; 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  height: 5em; 
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;   
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25rem;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
.under { z-index: 3; }
.above { z-index: 5; }
.footer {
  margin-top: 30rem;
  height: 5rem;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> Header</div>
<div id="contentMask"></div>
<div class="content">  DONT SHOW THIS DIV UNDER HEADER</div>
<div class="content under">  SHOW THIS DIV UNDER HEADER</div>
<div class="content above">  SHOW THIS DIV ABOVE HEADER</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

Comment: Would be a great solution but I want to hide, all elements with a specific class under the header. This divs can also be inside other divs that needs to be shown under the header...

Comment: @TheRealEricCartman please check my edit. Hope this works for you.

Comment: @A-meshu Check out the [codepen](https://codepen.io/eric_cartman/pen/wvvdyqB), I can't describe the problem very well...

Comment: Oh, now i see. I tried to set dynamically gradient background to `.content` that would "move" when the content  get to the header with scroll, but didn't succeed. Maybe someone else would succeed.